# Subplots don't show up in Canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

So I am trying to put a subplot with 9 graphs on my canvas in a GUI created with tkinter.

Everything is working fine and the subplots are shown in Spyder in the content manager however the Canvas only shows a blanc grid with two axes from 0 to 1

Here is the code:

```
self.fig_raw=plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
self.ax2=self.fig_raw.add_subplot(111) 

self.raw_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig_raw,self.mainframe)

def plot_data(self):
    self.fig_raw,self.ax2=plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(10,10))
    for i in np.arange(0,3,1):
        for j in np.arange(0,3,1):
            for ii in range (0,self.SData_Listbox.size()): 
                active_item=self.SData_Listbox.get(ii)
                self.ax2[i,j].contourf(self.z3D_signal[active_item][:,:,30])
                #axs[i,j].contourf(self.z3D_signal[active_item][:,:,30])
    #self.raw_canvas.set_title('Raw figure')

    self.raw_canvas.draw()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `self.raw_canva.pack()`?

Comment: Of course I did. I just forgot to put it in the code above. 

The subplots I want are drawn correctly and I can see them in Spyder’s content manager after I quit my GUI.

Comment: I can also see the canvas. The problem is there are only two axes and a blank surface on the canvas and not the 9 subplots I want to visualise ...